# Allowing access to a specific file in location block nginx config

Tags: nginx

In my nginx config I have been block all access from my IP however allowed to do that with my localhost. I would like to allow global access to one file of mine `xn.php` I try to do that with `location ^~ /xn.php` and it's not working. As well I tried `location /xn.php` and still fail. How should I do that? I checked a lot documentation however I stuck on it

```
server {
        listen   127.0.0.1:80;
        root /var/www/html/;
        index /index.php;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                deny 77.777.77.0/24;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                autoindex on;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri /index.html /index.php;
                deny all;
        }
        location ^~ /xn.php {
                allow all;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current configuration `xn.php` content would be send as HTTP response rather than being interpreted with PHP-FPM. Additionally, any request for PHP file won't be blocked with your `deny` rule since it won't match the `location / { ... }` block. You can try this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/;
        index /index.php;
        location / {
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
                autoindex on;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri /index.html /index.php;
        }
        location = /xn.php {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

**Update**

Since you are listening only on `127.0.0.1` interface this `server` block won't be reachable from any other host at all. Right configuration for you depends on other `server` blocks you have in your nginx config.

Comment: This config logically better of mine. However it's not working it's blocking all requests. On localhost and public ip as well. Maybe I wrong in `listen` block?

Comment: Maybe `allow 127.0.0.1` rule should be the first, and `deny all` the second. To listen on all interfaces use `listen 80` instead of `listen 127.0.0.1:80`, allow/deny rules should prevent other hosts to access any file other than `xn.php`.

Comment: In UPD 1 I added working solution. There are been a lot errors. Thanks

Comment: I think updated configuration would allow access to any PHP file from any host without allow/deny rules in the third block. I mean that `http://<ip>/` would be denied but `http://<ip>/index.php` would be allowed. Can you check it?

Comment: Yes, you right. It's allowing to get some text/html content

Comment: I'm updated proposed config, can you check it? I think this one should work as expected blocking every other host for any content except `xn.php`.

Comment: Yes, this is great. Working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Update your nginx location config a bit

```
        location /xn.php {
                allow all;
                autoindex on;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
```

Comment: Well, tu I did but still the same

Comment: What the error message? Maybe basic auth  is better solution in your case https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/#configuring-nginx-and-nginx-plus-for-http-basic-authentication

Comment: Thank you. I been updated my answer. There are been about 3 mistakes in config